# Livewire how to store image in multiple location in side public folder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

hello im new in livewire now converting my laravel 8 project with laravel 10 with livewire 2, now im facing one error in livewire controller when uploading image file, my laravel 8 controller image upload i made it storing 3 different folder in side public folder in laravel it works perfect.
now im making same in livewire controller but im getting error when im going to submit.

> my error i get in livewire

```
Could not move the file "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\phpADC5.tmp" to "D:\project\livewire\livewire\public\/FOLDER_ONE\1689425855.png" ().
```

> MY LARAVEL 8 CODE

```
public function Store_Enrollment(Request $request)

{
    
    
    $input['user_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->user_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('FOLDER_ONE/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['user_photo']; // path 1
    $request->user_photo->move($folder1, $input['user_photo']); // path 1
    $path2 = public_path('FOLDER_TWO/') . $input['user_photo']; // path 2
    $path3 = public_path('FOLDER_THREE/') . $input['user_photo']; // path 3
    \File::copy($path1, $path2); \File::copy($path1, $path3); 
   
    User::create($input); 

}
```

> MY LIVEWIRE 2 CODE

```
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
class Enrollment extends Component
{ 
     use WithFileUploads;
     public $user_photo;

    public function submit() 
    { 
        $input['user_photo'] = time().'.'.$this->user_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder1 = public_path('FOLDER_ONE/');
        $path1 = $folder1 . $input['student_photo']; // path 1
        $this->user_photo->move($folder1, $input['user_photo']); // image saved in first folder
        $path2 = public_path('FOLDER_TWO/') . $input['user_photo']; // path 2
        $path3 = public_path('FOLDER_THREE/') . $input['user_photo']; // path 3
        \File::copy($path1, $path2); \File::copy($path1, $path3); 

        User::create($input); 
    }
}
```